# How can I represent this statement in first order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to write the statement below into first order logic:

```
If someone is a friend of a popstar, then they are a popstar too.
```

My question is in regards to the quantifiers. Not sure if they are correct:

$$\forall x \, \exists y\, (\,(\, \mathrm{Friend}(x, y)\, \&\, \mathrm{Popstar}(y)\, ) \to \mathrm{Popstar}(x)\,).$$

Comment: The position of the quantifier $\exists y$ is not correct. What you are saying now is of the form "for all x there exists some y such that \ldots", but that's not really what you need. Think of it.

Comment: Perhaps this? `exists x exists y ((Friend(x, y) & Popstar(y)) -> Popstar(x)).`. Meaning that: "There is some x who is friend of some y who is also a popstar..."

Comment: No, the quantifier $\exists y$ is still in the same (wrong) place. The only thing you need to do to correct your original sentence is to move that quantifier to the right place. Now you have instead introduced another mistake: the quantification of $x$. In the latest version, your sentence asserts that there exists an element $x$ with certain properties. The statement you are trying to translate is not of this form: it says that something is true for all elements $x$ (namely that _if_ x is friends with a pop star, _then_ $x$ is a pop star, too).

Comment: Perhaps you can think in several steps:
First, consider the predicate $\mathrm{IFWAPS}(x)$, which expresses that $x$ is friends with a pop star. Try to write the sentence using this predicate, the predicate $\mathrm{Popstar}(x)$ and logical connectives ($\forall$, $\exists$, $\&$, $\to$ etc.). 
Next, try to formulate $\mathrm{IFWAPS}(x)$ using logical connectives and the predicates $\mathrm{Friend}(x,y)$ and $\mathrm{Popstar}(y)$.
Last, in your formula from the first step, replace $\mathrm{IFWAPS}(x)$ with the expression that you found in the second step.

Comment: Got it(I think): `all x ((exists y (Friend(x, y) & Popstar(y))) -> Popstar(x)).`. I'll start working soon. Check your reply later today.

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the statement `If someone is a friend of a popstar, then they are a popstar too.`.

The first order logic for it can be represented as:

$\qquad\forall x\,\big(\exists y\,(\operatorname{Friend}(x, y)\,\&\,\operatorname{Popstar}(y)) \to \operatorname{Popstar}(x)\big)$