# How can I represent the statement below in first order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to write the statement below into first order logic:

> My dog Jude is drinking something from the bowl, and everything from the bowl contains germs except for potable water.

I'm using the following predicates `Drinks(x,y)`, `From(x,y)`, `Bowl(x)`, `ContainsGerm(x)`, `PotableWater(x)`.

Not 100% sure about the correctness of the logic and quantifiers that I'm using here, so any advice or suggestion of alternative solution to be discussed is welcome:

$\small\exists x \exists y (({\operatorname{Drinks}(\operatorname{Jude},x)} ~\&~ {\operatorname{Bowl}(y)} ~\&~ {\operatorname{From}(x,y)} ~\&~ (\forall z ({\operatorname{From}(z, y)} ~\&~ {\lnot\operatorname{PotableWater}(z)}) \to \operatorname{ContainsGerm}(z)))$

Comment: "the bowl" sounds like an atom. `exists y Bowl(y)` would more likely be "a bowl" at its first appearance.

Comment: Agree, but in this case I need to handle it as a property of an entity. So it's a unary predicate. I've already raised this question with the person who proposed the exercise and it's in fact an unary predicate.

Comment: But "Jude" isn't?

Comment: No, it's a constant. The description of the question is accurate.

Comment: That's fair if those are given requirements, but there's no obvious reason for the difference just from the English, in which both "My dog Jude" and "the bowl" are definite noun phrases.

Comment: Notice the `all z` part doesn't involve `x`, so you could rearrange the statement as `exists y (exists x (...) & exists z (...))`. This rewrite makes sense because once we've identified the bowl in question, the sentence is really the AND of two statements: one about Jude drinking and one about the contents of the bowl.

Comment: Good catch. It would be something like `exists y (exists x (Drinks(Jude,x) & Bowl(y) & From(x,y)) & (all z (From(z, y) & -PotableWater(z)) -> ContainsGerm(z))).` ,right? I'll wait few more minutes and mark this as an answer if no one else comment here.

Comment: Yes, I meant `all z` instead of `exists z` there.

Comment: 2. Please start using mathjax, as edited (e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4463002/21813)) on your behalf in your previous questions. Your latest suggestion, when typed as `$$\exists y (\exists x (\text{Drinks}(\text{Jude},x) \land \text{Bowl}(y) \land \text{From}(x,y)) \\\land \forall z (\text{From}(z, y) (\land \lnot\text{PotableWater}(z)) →\text{ContainsGerm}(z))).$$`, will display as $$∃y (∃x (\text{Drinks}(\text{Jude},x) \land \text{Bowl}(y) \land \text{From}(x,y)) \\\land (∀z (\text{From}(z, y) \land \lnot\text{PotableWater}(z)) →\text{ContainsGerm}(z))).$$

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll start using mathjax from now onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the statement:

> My dog Jude is drinking something from the bowl, and everything from the bowl contains germs except for potable water.

The logic representation of it is:

$$\exists y (\exists x (\text{Drinks}(\text{Jude},x) \land \text{Bowl}(y) \land \text{From}(x,y)) \\\land \forall z (\text{From}(z, y) (\land \lnot\text{PotableWater}(z)) →\text{ContainsGerm}(z))).$$

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit (to illustrate what I meant above regarding > versus ` when quoting text). And, more elaborate: `$( \big( \Big( \bigg($` gives $( \big( \Big( \bigg(,$ and `$∃y() \quad ∃y\,()$` gives $∃y() \quad ∃y\,().$